# Java Insert a Character 2D Array with a Blank Space

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to insert a blank space to all the elements of a 2D character array. Does this work?

```
public class AsciiDisplay {

  private char [][] grid;

  public AsciiDisplay() {
    grid = new char [30][15];
  }

  public void updateGrid() {


  //Here is the code to initialize all the elements on my 2D char array with a blank space.
    for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; i <grid[0].length; i++) {
        grid[i][j] = ' ';
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: does this work? why dont you compile it yourself and let us answer why does'nt it compile !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a correction  your loop should be like below because inside second loop you need to loop on array which you get in the first loop.

```
for(int j = 0; j <grid[i].length; j++) {
```

Comment: Thanks, solved all those weird things printing on the console!

Comment: I am not sure if the problem description was correct. Even `grid[0].length` should work. I think the problem was due to `i++` being used.

Answer (score 0):

If your grid is square or rectangle one then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in second loop.

`for(int j = 0; i <grid[0].length; i++) {` as you are using `i++`

Change it to `j++`

I think `grid[0].length` part is fine as all rows will have same length.